# How can I use console output to debug pthread interaction with JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, pthreads

I made an example which creates a pthread to print a message. 
But the output is unexpected.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Before call native thread");
// invoke the native method to print a message
int socketId = new SocketJNI().createSocket(); //line 7
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("After call native thread");//line 9: create break point here
```

C code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_SocketJNI_createSocket(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, createSocket, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void* createSocket(void *arg) 
{
    printf("Inside native thread(pthread)");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
Before call native thread
After call native thread
Inside native thread(pthread)
```

But I think it should be:

```
Before call native thread
Inside native thread(pthread)
After call native thread
```

So, what is the problem? How does pthread work?

Update:

When I reach line 8(on debugging), the pthread(create in line 7) don't print message, It print only:

```
Before call native thread
```

I wait, and wait but not thing print
After line 9:

```
Before call native thread
After call native thread
```

Comment: How should we answer this without any snippet of code? Crystal balls are hard to get these days.

Comment: Your native code and your Java code do not necessarily (i.e. *probably don't*) use the same streams for output.  You imply that your native call is spawning a new thread via pthreads, but you should state explicitly whether that is the case.

Comment: I updated my question with C code.

"don't use the same streams for output" (@technomage) may be what I need to know. Is there any document about it, @technomage?

Comment: Try putting a "\n" at the end of your `printf`, or anyways flush the stdout in the C code.

Comment: Do you have the debugger configured to suspend all threads when you hit a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure your output is flushed as soon as you send it, either turn off buffering on `System.out` or use `System.err`.  On the native side, use `stderr` (unbuffered) instead of `stdout`.  You can also use `System.out.flush()` in Java and `fflush(stdout)` in C to force output of any buffered data.

Note that you still might get some unexpected results, since Java and C don't use the same buffers for output streams, and there's nothing preventing the two outputs from intermixing on their way to the terminal.  In practice, though, you'll likely see the output as soon as you flush it (or as soon as it's output if unbuffered).

As for when your thread actually runs, it'll be sometime *after* you create it.  Unless you put in some explicit synchronization, it may not run until long after your Java method has returned.  It's up to the system to start the new thread (outside of Java), so any number of factors might delay the thread's start, including system load, memory swapping, etc.

Comment: This is what I look for...!
    System.out.flush(), and fflush(stdout) force output of buffered data. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep(2000) is not the way you should be synchronizing threads.
the parent thread should join the child thread if you want the parent to wait for the child thread.
Here is the createSocket which you should use.

```
Java_SocketJNI_createSocket(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
   pthread_t thread;
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, createSocket, NULL);
   pthread_join(thread,NULL); 
   return 0;
}
```